# How to call a method from a class, using the unknown name of an object created by that class?

Tags: c++, function, class, variables, std

I'm trying to use the func afficherEtat, using the object name that the user typed in :

*Personnage.hpp*

```
#ifndef PERSONNAGE_HPP_INCLUDED
#define PERSONNAGE_HPP_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Personnage { public: Personnage(std::string nomPerso); void afficherEtat() const; 
private: std::string m_nomPerso;    };  
#endif
```

*Personnage.cpp*

```
#include "Personnage.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
Personnage::Personnage(string nomPerso) : m_nomPerso(nomPerso) {}
void Personnage::afficherEtat() const
{    cout << "Le nom : " << m_nomPerso << endl;}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Personnage.hpp" 
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    string creaPersoFini("y");
    int nombrePerso(0);
    vector<string> tableauNomPerso;
    string nomPerso;

    while(creaPersoFini!="n")
    {
        cout << "Entrez le nom du personnage : ";
        cin >> nomPerso;
        tableauNomPerso.push_back(nomPerso);
        Personnage(nomPerso);
        cout << "Voulez vous creer un autre personnage ? y/n ";  
        cin >> creaPersoFini;
        nombrePerso++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<=nombrePerso; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << tableauNomPerso[i] << endl;
        nomPerso = tableauNomPerso[i];
        nomPerso.afficherEtat();                // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        cout << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to allow the user to create multiple Personnage, using the class Personnage. I don't know in advance how many he will create or their name. I put the name that he entered into a vector.
What i need now is to call the method afficherEtat, using the name the user entered. I get it from the vector and put it into a variable, that i'm using to call the method from the class Personnage.

If i create the object with a name i choose myself in the main(), it works, like david.afficherEtat();
But with a user input and a variable it doesn't.

The error i get while compiling is:

```
error: 'std::__cxx11::string {aka class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' has no member named 'afficherEtat'|
```

EDIT : WORKING CODE

```
int main()
{
    string creaPersoFini("y");
    vector<Personnage> tableauPerso;    // Tableau de Personnage, pas de string
    string nomPerso;

    while(creaPersoFini!="n")
    {
        cout << "Entrez le nom du personnage : ";
        cin >> nomPerso;
        Personnage newP(nomPerso);              // new temp person
        tableauPerso.push_back(newP);           // add the person
        cout << "Voulez vous creer un autre personnage ? y/n ";
        cin >> creaPersoFini;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<tableauPerso.size(); i++)        // <, pas <=, sinon ça affiche 1 vide.
    {
        cout << endl;
        tableauPerso[i].afficherEtat();
        cout << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

I didn't change Personnage.cpp or Personnage.hpp

Comment: You might want `vector<Personnage> tableauNomPerso;` and `tableauNomPerso.emplace_back(nomPerso);` instead of `push_back`

Comment: It's not possible to change names of functions or variables at runtime. You can't "make" a variable called **David** and then one called **Mary**. You can only change the values. You need to convert the vector to the People if you want to call a function, else it would be called on the string, hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is right. You're calling a function defined in `Personnage` but on `string`. The problem is with your design. Don't make a list of names, make a list of people.

I think you are misunderstanding what the code does. When you enter the name of a person, that is the variable inside the class, not the name of the variable.

`Personnage(nomPerso);` doesn't add a variable with the name `David` that is of type `Personnage`. It calls the constructor and assigns the name `David` to a new temporary instance of `Personnage`. You can change the value of variables at run-time, not their name. If you have a variable called `sum_of_numbers` you can't magically change it to `blah_blah_numbers` inside the code. You can't do this in **any** language.

If you want to enumerate all names the person entered via a person, this is what you can do:

```
int main()
{
    string creaPersoFini("y");
    int nombrePerso(0);
    vector<Personnage> tableauPerso;  // change to people and delete the total number

    while(creaPersoFini!="n")
    {
        cout << "Entrez le nom du personnage : ";
        cin >> nomPerso;
        Personnage newP(nomPerso);        // new temp person
        tableauPerso.push_back(newP);     // add the person
        cout << "Voulez vous creer un autre personnage ? y/n ";  
        cin >> creaPersoFini;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<=tableauPerso.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << tableauPerso[i].afficherEtat() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OK, now a few things about your code:

1. Because you included <string> in the header, there is no need to do it in the cpp, if you also include the header that included string (in your case `Personnage.hpp`)
2. next, always include stdlib headers **first**, then any OS related ones and lastly yours; don't mix and match
3. `nombrePerso` is irrelevant; just use `tableauNomPerso.size()`

Now a few things about my code:

1. when working with objects and storing whatever data you want about them, always see if you need the data or the objects themselves; if you would have only displayed the name, then yes, a `vector<string>` would have been fine, but since you wanted to also call a function, then you needed the object instead
2. when working with objects you need to instantiate them using `new`; this allocates the memory needed for the class as well as performs all initialization calls; when the object is no longer needed, it needs to be removed using `delete`; this deallocates the memory after calling the destructor; I used static initialization here since it was all done in the same scope, and to simplify it, but normally you need to `new` them and to remember to `delete` them when the program ends

Comment: `// new temp person` is absolutely unnecessary and not optimal.

Comment: *there is no need to do it in the cpp* is not a good advise. Header file can be changed whereas source files can continue use of strings.

Comment: *always include stdlib headers first* also is not a good advise. The fist #include should be a header file whose declarations are implemented in a current source file. After that you are correct.

Comment: Using `new` and `delete` is a bad advise. You don't use them in the answer, why do you suggest them?

Comment: 1. // new temp person - it's not, but his code is not optimized and the point was not to optimize it, but adapt it; I am not trying to reinvent the wheel, just to correct his code; 2. "there is no need to do it in the cpp" - I am not generalizing, I am only talking about **this** context, in which case it is correct, unless you can forward declare std::string (which you cannot and you know that); 3. usually yes, but depending on what you include in the headers, I found I reduce a lot more conflicts if I let the "system" get what it needs first;

Comment: 4. why is `new` and `delete` bad advice? That's how you use objects and you also know that, else you get the whole "out of scope" problem. I don't use them, yes, but I am sure he can read up about new and delete which is why I did not include it in the code. Sorry, but I am not sure you're using "bad advice" properly. You are welcome to post your own answer if you disagree with mine.

Comment: I had to adapt a few details but it worked ! 
However when i ran the program I had the wanted result in the consol, and also planty of random non ascii caracters.. I didnt change anything and rerun it and it worked wonders. Do you know why it did that and solved itself ?