# Do i need to delete newP (temp) after using it?

Tags: c++, new-operator, temp

I asked a question about a code and someone recommended i used newP to add a class to a vector, it works, but i dont fully understand the concept behind that way of doing.

```
string creaPersoFini("y");
    vector<Personnage> tableauPerso;    // Tableau de Personnage, pas de string
    string nomPerso;
    int nbPerso(3);

    cout << "Trois personnages maximum, pour l'instant." << endl;
    while(creaPersoFini!="n" && nbPerso < 4)
    {
        cout << "Entrez le nom du personnage : ";
        cin >> nomPerso;
        Personnage newP(nomPerso);              // new temp person
        tableauPerso.push_back(newP);           // add the person
        cout << "Voulez vous creer un autre personnage ? y/n ";
        cin >> creaPersoFini;
    }
```

Is this correct ? Do i need to delete the newP after adding it to the vector ? I know that if you create a pointer with new it is necessary to delete it afterward, is this what is happening here or not at all ?

I tried to look on internet and stackoverflow for an answer, but i only found parts of answers or quesitons/answers that are too complex for my current knowledge of C++.

If someone could explain to me in a simple way the difference between new/delete, newP and temporary using like these (or point me in a direction where i can find an answer) i'd be grateful !

Here is [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74943834/how-to-call-a-method-from-a-class-using-the-unknown-name-of-an-object-created-b?noredirect=1#comment132253356_74943834) to the question where he recommended it, i used it because it works but since there was disagrement in the comments i'm not sure, and i'd like to be.

Comment: ***Do i need to delete newP (temp) after using it?*** No, If you don't use `new` you don't use `delete`. In modern `c++` its recommended to avoid using `new` and instead use containers from the standard library (or smart pointers) where the memory management is automatic. You have done this in your code by not using `new` and using a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The whole question can be sidestepped by using `std::vector::emplace_back()`.

Comment: Why would you think you need to use `delete` when you did not use `new`? Also only pointers can be deleted and `newP` does not appear to be a pointer.

Comment: Also, if you didn't know `emplace_back` existed, you could have done: `tableauPerso.push_back({nomPerso});` without having to create `Personnage newP(nomPerso);`.

Comment: `newP` in your code is an object with automatic storage duration, so automatically ceases to exist at the end of the enclosing scope (effectively at the enclosing closing `}` of your loop body). `tableauPerso.push_back(newP)` appends a *copy* of `newP` to the vector. A `new` expression (which you haven't used) dynamically creates an object, which will exist (as far as your program is concerned) until a corresponding `delete` expression. Using `delete` on anything not created with a corresponding `new` (e.g. attempting to use `delete` to destroy `newP` in any way) gives undefined behaviour.